# How to use router.push for same path, different query parameter in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router

Current url is

```
/?type=1
```

I want to use router.push on this page.

```
this.$router.push('/?type=2');
```

But this gives NavigationDuplicated error.

I don't want to use params like

```
/:type
```

Comment: So how did you solve it? You made some comments that you were able to solve it, but you don't say how. Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's not different from your current path.
If the value of `type` is different it won't give you `NavigationDuplicated` error.
you can separate query like below too to make sure it will be understandable by the framework:

```js
this.$router.push({
   path: '/',
   query: { type: 2 },
});
```

Comment: This doesn't re-render the component.

Comment: OK, anyway I found how to control NavigationDuplicated error. I need to make another question for the component issue. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't actually work as pointed out by @JeongyongLee the router does not push to the same path although the query has changed

Comment: This does not solve the issue. Rather navigates you to the root of your router and does not stay in the same path but with new params.

Answer (score 9):

Aliraza already answered your questions but I am sharing this answer because I see your comments asking, component don't rerender, for rerendering components you need to watch params like this:

```
 watch: {
    '$route.params': 'functionToRunWhenParamsChange',
  }
```

Comment: A solution that works for me. But for anyone want to use this method, be aware to add null checker, because when we leave the route, this callback would be called again and the params is undefined this time.

Answer (score 3):

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2872). They're using `this.$router.replace` but I imagine it shares the same root cause as when you are using `this.$router.push`. The proposed solution / workaround is to use an empty `catch` chained to the `$router` call, so:

```js
this.$router.push('/?type=2').catch(err => {})
```

**EDIT**

You can pass the query params as an object to the second parameter of `this.$router.push` as well:

```js
this.$router.push({ query: { type: 2 } })
```

Comment: This doesn't re-render the component.

Comment: OK, anyway I found how to control NavigationDuplicated error. I need to make another question for the component issue. Thank you!

Answer (score -4):

If you wanna change your url (I mean push to another web page) and reload that page, you should use this syntax:

```js
window.location.href = "your-url"
```

GG