# Is there any workaround for "NavigationDuplicated" exception in Vue.js when pushing query parameters in the url while remaining on the same path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url-routing, vuetify.js, vue-router

Current url is

```
/search
```

New url should be

```
/search?foo=bar
```

I just want to update my query params being on the same route as a result of application of some filters on the page

My code:

```
this.$router.push({query: params})
```

There is a way to handle the "NavigationDuplicated" error using a catch block but that only supresses the error, the query parameters in the route are still not updated.

Related issue:

[How to use router.push for same path, different query parameter in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428227)

But this gives the path '/' but i need to remain on the same page

Comment: Although it doesn't solve your problem, a workaround would be to completely reload the page, or store the values in a state storage like vuex 

Comment: neither are feasible, reloading the entire page on a filter is just bad UX and storing the values would not make the url shareable to others.If someone opens the same url it should reapply those filters

Comment: It does, you write the query params to a vuex store, and read them from there instead from the queries. If the page is loaded, you check the queries and store them into the vuex storage.

Comment: @WajihSiddiqui ? You probably has error in your router file. Can you paste it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `catch` to workaround this error:

```js
this.$router.push({query:params}).catch(() => {})
```

Comment: what will this error handler do exactly, the task i wanted to achieve (pushing param into url) failed, can't add this statement in the catch again

Answer (score 0):

You can use history.pushState(), it will modify the URL without pushing the router.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71042001/19222560