# VueJS : Dynamically change the URL depending on filters

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a project for which I use VueJS (2.x) for the frontend part.
I've made a component to do some filtering :

[image]

And I'd like to be able to change the URL according to the filters, so that I can share the URL and another user would land on the same search. At the stage of my screenshot, the URL should look like : `my/long/url?username=test&email=@test`. But I don't know how to achieve it.

Currently, when I add/remove a filter, I create a new `URLSearchParams` object that I commit to the vuex store and with a `watch` statement I query my backend again with the updated filters.

The thing is that my URL doesn't change, of course, because I do not pass by a `this.$router.push(...)` or whatever.

Maybe I started it wrong.

What is the good way of achieving this ? Knowing that routing to the same view with a new query part does trigger the error `DuplicateNavigation`...

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had achieved something similar to this by using the `history.pushState`
This basically allows you to modify your URL even if you are not using `$router.push`

You can follow the URL for more details
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been able to do what I wanted, which is modifying the URL without triggering anything !

Comment: $router.replace works too for some similar cases. But for your purpose, yes history.pushState seems to be optimal.